# Vue.js: Return image with method after axios.get

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, base64

```
<li v-for="people in projectData.employees" :key="people._id">
    <b-img :src="colleagueImages(people)" 
</li>
```

```
async colleagueImages(people) {
  console.log(people); // => max@stackoverflow.com
  let profileImage = await axios.get("http://myapilink.com/image?id=" + people + "&s=200&def=avatar", {
    headers: {
      'accept': 'image/jpeg'
    }
  });
  console.log(profileImage);
  return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(
    new Uint8Array(profileImage.data)
    .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
  );
}
```

The console.log(profileImage) returns the following:

[image: Chrome console.log]
The API I am using is returning a Base64 Image.

With my current code I only get the following error in my browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, got Promise.

Comment: An `async` returns a pending Promise. You need to use regular Vue `data` for the `src`, and change the `src` in your function.

Comment: I am thinking that this would also not work as I have to get the images multiple times and then I would always overwrite my ```data```, would'nt I?

Comment: If you have multiple images you need to use an Object or Array instead of a single variable. async updates app state, app state determines HTML.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought that I can resolve the Promise or just save the Promise result to a variable and return it through my method.

Comment: The problem is that while `src = await async(...);` sets src to the returned result, you're using `src = async();`, which sets src to the Promise.

Comment: Would I really need an ```async``` function? I did not do this on purpose and only thought that it would be the solution at the beginning.

Comment: `axios.get` / AJAX / fetch() is asynchronous. Otherwise loading the image would make the browser freeze.

Comment: Usually you don't need to download in image, encode its data in base64 and put that string in a src attribute: you could simply put that URL in the src attribute (bonus: the browser will cache images). But I think the question still deserves an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have all the data you need to render in the first place, you have to change attributes afterwards. First, you need to use Vue components for your items, so your "src" attribute will be reactive; second, you start the requests for your items after you rendered your app. Please see this mockup.

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: `
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle()"
          v-bind:checked="done">
        <del v-if="done">
          {{ text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ text }}
        </span>

        <span v-if="like">
            ♥ {{like}}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    `,
  props: ['id', 'text', 'done', 'like'],
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
        this.done = !this.done
    }
  }
})
let todos = [
      {id: 0, text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, like: null },
      {id: 1, text: "Learn Vue", done: false, like: null },
      {id: 2, text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true, like: null },
      {id: 3, text: "Build something awesome", done: true, like: null }
    ]
const v = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: todos
  }
})

todos.forEach((item) => {
    // This is just a mock for an actual network request
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        item.like = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
    }, Math.random() * 2000)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/willywongi/gsLqda2y/20/

In this example I have the basic todo-list app with a fake "like" count for each item, which is calculated asynchronously. After setting up my app, I wait for the "like" attribute values (in my example I just wait a random value of milliseconds).